# Normalization by z-score + range [0,1]

Tags: normalization, standardization, z-score, range

I am trying to normalize my dataset for further analysis. I have several data coming from different subjects, so I have first applied z-score normalization to each variable of each subject in order to avoid inter-subject variability.

Though, this doesn't normalize the data to a range such as [0,1], and I need normalized data so as to use some algorithms like kNN classifiers. Hence, I have normalized each variable (taking data of all the subjects) to the range [0,1], but I am a bit confused.

Does this make sense? Does this second transformation affect the inter-subject variability normalization?

Thank you!

Comment: PCA does *not* require that your data are normalized. This procedure doesn't seem like a good thing to do.

Comment: Thanks @gung, I've changed the example to kNN. Why do you think this is not the right thing to do? How would you do it?

Comment: Read quite a nice discussion on this topic [here](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_about_feature_scaling.html)